# Detect element hiding/showing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to keep watch on a specific element, and trigger a function whenever the visibility of the element changes; visible vs. hidden?

I've tried with ways like `new window.MutationObserver`, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Please specify what kind of visibility. The `hidden` attribute? The `visibility` style? Other?
Normally, it feels like a MutationObserver would indeed be the way to go, and quick google suggests it works even for style changes. I suggest looking over the API for `MutationRecord`, specifically `mutation.attributeName === 'style'`. Edit: sorry this assumed it was a HTML question because of mentioning `MutationObserver`, but now I noticed it's tagged pure javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) and check the element's [`intersectionRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio):

```js
index=0,setInterval(() => elem.style.display = ++index % 2 == 0 ? "block" : "none", 1000)
// ^^^flicker effect^^^

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((elems, obs) => {
  if(elems[0].intersectionRatio == 0) {
    console.log('elem hidden')
  } else {
    console.log('elem shown')
  }
})
observer.observe(elem)
```

```html
<div id="elem">Flickering text</div>
```